# Getting a 401 error when submitting my datapayload to urbanairship

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to send a test notification to my ipod via UrbanAirship with C#. I've tried many code snippets trying to send my notification to UrbanAirship from my Windows server, yet I always end up with a 401 error.

Here's my latest code:

```
string postData = "{\"aps\": {\"badge\": 1, \"alert\": \"Hello from Urban Airship!\"}, \"device_tokens\": [\""+ devToken +"\"]}";

var uri = new Uri("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/");
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
char[] charArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData));
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = encoding.GetByteCount(charArray);

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
   stream.Close();
   var response = request.GetResponse();
   response.Close();
}
```

Note: I've verified that my username and password are correct.

===UPDATE===

I would say that there's something woring with my urbanairship config or so but the following worked:

```
curl -X PUT -u "appKey:appSecret" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"alias": "myalias"}' https://go.urbanairship.com/api/device_tokens/myTOken/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I've modified my code and most important: YOUR PASSWORD IS THE APPLICATION MASTER SECRET

```
string postData = "{\"aps\": {\"badge\": 1, \"alert\": \"Hello from Urban Airship!\"}, \"device_tokens\": [\""+ devToken +"\"]}";

var uri = new Uri("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/");
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
char[] charArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData));
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = encoding.GetByteCount(charArray);

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
    stream.Close();
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
}
```